# Add a style to a generated TextBlock

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I would like to add a custom style to a generated textblock.

```
        TextBlock title = new TextBlock();
        title.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["styleTheke"];
        title.Text = "test";
        stackMenu.Children.Add(title);
```

This style is defined in

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="styleTheke" TargetType="TextBlock">
   <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
  </Style>
 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

However .. the Textblock always appears "unstyled".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the resource is in the same page then you can refer to it via:

```
(Style) Resources["styleTheke"];
```

The `Application.Current.Resources` Dictionary is for resources (typically) defined in `App.xaml`.

Comment: I tried that earlier. Once my program reaches that point I get an exception which states "unspecified error". ( the same happens with this.Resources..

Comment: @theXs The project at http://cid-cc22250598bf7f04.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/SO-4499984.zip shows using both types of resources in dynamically generated textblocks

Comment: I found the error in my code. You cannot have the property "width" set to "AUTO", after I took that out - it worked.